# Graphs, multiplicative graphs and composition graphs (à la Ehresmann)

Tags: reference-request, terminology

**Introduction.** Allow me to use the NBG axiomatic system as a foundation (*). Charles Ehresmann is acknowledged as the first one to have introduced the idea of *multiplicative graphs* as a further level of abstraction in the study of categories. Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of his *Categories et structures* on my shelves, thus I'm writing to ask for experts' advice on the subject.

I learnt from uncle Google that Lutz Schröder, in his 1999 PhD thesis (in German), has slightly further abstracted Ehresmann's original ideas by extending multiplicative graphs to *composition graphs*. But Schröder's thesis is not apparently available for free consultation through the web and, in addition, I cannot read German. Now, the point is that I would like to see a *completely formal* definition of Schröder's composition graphs, for the sake of comparison with something on which I'm currently working. So, this post is definitely another question about terminology and references.

**Definitions.** As far as I can understand, a *graph* (in the sense of Ehresmann) is a 5-tuple $\mathbf C = (\mathcal C_{\rm o}, \mathcal C_{\rm h}, s, t, i)$, consisting of two classes $\mathcal C_{\rm o}$ and $\mathcal C_{\rm h}$ (of objects and arrows, respectively), and functions $s,t: \mathcal C_{\rm h} \to \mathcal C_{\rm o}$ and $i: \mathcal C_{\rm o} \to \mathcal C_{\rm h}$ such that $s(i(A)) = t(i(A)) = A$ for all $A \in \mathcal C_{\rm o}$. Thus, if I'm not missing anything, Ehresmann's graphs *have* identities. The same *should be* true with a *composition graph* (in the sense of Schröder), which *seems* to be a pair $(\mathbf C, c)$, where $\mathbf C = (\mathcal C_{\rm o}, \mathcal C_{\rm h}, s, t, i)$ is a graph (in the sense of Ehresmann) and $c$ is a partial function from $\mathcal C_{h} \times \mathcal C_{h}$ to $\mathcal C_{\rm h}$ such that $(f,g) \in {\rm dom}(c)$ only if $t(f) = s(g)$. This *should be* indeed called

1. a *multiplicative graph* (in the sense of Ehresmann) if the 'if' in the latter statement is replaced with an 'if and only if';
2. an *identitive composition graph* if for $f \in \mathcal C_{\rm h}$ one has
   $c(f,i(t(f))) = f$ whenever $(f,i(t(f))) \in {\rm dom}(c)$ and $c(i(s(f)),f) = f$ whenever $(i(s(f)),f) \in {\rm dom}(c)$;
3. a *strongly identitive composition graph* if it is identitive and $(f,i(t(f))), (i(s(f)),f) \in {\rm dom}(c)$ for all $f$;
4. a *semicategory* if it is an *associative* composition graph, viz $c(c(f,g),h),c(f,c(g,h)) \in {\rm dom}(c)$ and $c(c(f,g),h) = c(f,c(g,h))$  whenever $(f,h),(g,h) \in {\rm dom}(c)$ (which is slightly more general than the homonymous notion of a semicategory given by nLab).

> > **Questions.** (1) Do these definitions reflect the *actual* ones of graphs, composition graphs (by Schröder) and multiplicative graphs (by Ehresmann)? (2) Do you know of any significant development of these topics, especially in relation to categorical logic?

See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106898/references-for-semicategories) something related and motivations.

(*) Yeah, I know. Some of you feel disgusted by the NBG stuff, for diverse and diverse reasons. But, please, refrain yourselves from annoying comments on this hand, since the personal taste of Mr Banana is not really the point, here. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you are lucky, a citation search on the dissertation might reveal a non-German version which provides enough info for you to reconstruct the definition.  Have you tried that?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.20

Comment: Of course, I did. On the bottom of page 4 in _Monads on composition graphs_ (in "Applied Categorical Structures", Vol. 10, 2002), it is Schröder himself who claims that the definition of a composition graph given in the paper is somewhat informal (and I must really agree with him), while inviting the interested reader to look at his 1999 PhD thesis for something more formal.